# Are application assignments in Datascience common practice?

Tags: r, data, homework

this might seem off topic, but I hope this question will be tolerated.

I was recently asked to help a friend with an assignment in the process of applying for a new job as data scientist. And honestly I had a lot of fun solving the assignment for me and giving him guidance on how to proceed

However this got me wondering about a few things:

- is it common practice in Datascience to hand out assignments to applicants?
- is there a database available with datascience assignments, because I enjoy doing them?

Comment: Pretty common in software engineering, perhaps someone else can comment about data science. I would like to point out that: (a) It is expected that work on such assignments is done *alone* in order to assess the candidate - your help might land your friend a job that they cannot do (are you going tohelp them do their job for free in your spare time?) and (b) someone might compile copies of interview assigments but again that is counter to the purpose of such assignments, your preparation should be *general* on data science skills, not ready-made high scoring solutions.

Comment: In short, getting a job that you are not ready for, by boosting interview test results, is a recipe for later misery for you and your employer. Think twice before trying to gain advantage to get the job, and check whether you would be facing similar challenges in the actual job where you will have no help and no prepared work, yet be expected to produce results daily

Comment: Well while the ethical implications were clear to me I didnt hand out my results to my friend, I rather gave him tips where to start. I solved them for myself because it was fun to me. Let me rephrase the purpose of this Q: I am looking for datascience assignments because they are fun to me, not to boost my job interview (I got a job)

Comment: Then perhaps drop the detail about the task being for a job interview, as it is not relevant, and ask how to find some fun assignments. Describe the assignment, and what you liked about it. If you have not heard of Kaggle then check https://www.kaggle.com/ which has hundreds of ML training/tuning tasks - if you have heard of Kaggle, then please explain what was different about the task you did that made it fun for you.